# Why my while loop will ask for input again even it is match the condition

Tags: python, while-loop

```
class volunteer:
    def __init__ (self, name, age, type, hourContribution):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__type = type
        self.__hourContribution = hourContribution
```

This is the class of volunteer

```py
check = True
name = input("Name of volunteer? ")
age = int(input("Age? "))
type = input("Type of volunteer ('F/P/E/T'): ")
type = type.lower()
while check != False:
    if type == "f" or type == "p" or type == "e" or type == "t":
        check = False
    elif type != "f" or type != "p" or type != "e" or type != "t":
        print ("Invalid type! Please enter again!")
        type = input("Type of volunteer ('F/P/E/T'): ")

hourCont = int(input("Contribution hour? "))
while hourCont <= 0:
    print ("Invalid value! Please enter again!")
    hourCont = int(input("Contribution hour? "))

newGroup.addVolunteer(volunteer(name, age, type, hourCont))
print ("... Volunteer has been added successfully.")
```

I can't figure why the first while loop will keep on asking for input even it match the condition.

Comment: What specifically do you think should happen instead? why? When you start the loop `while check != False`, where did the value of `check` come from?

Comment: Also, `type` is a terrible choice of variable name, since it hides the `type` builtin, and `type != "f" or type != "p" or type != "e" or type != "t"` doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: If I enter `d` for the type, it keeps asking it doesn't go at hourCont

Comment: Works fine for me, if the input is type = d, it will again ask to enter the type of volunteer

Comment: please post a minimal and runnable example of your problem; we don't know what newGroup is and the validation has nothing to do with name and age

Comment: If I enter d for type, it will go to hourCont. But it shouldn't go for the hourCont right, should be ask the input again

Comment: try to fix your formatting `print ("hi")` should be `print("hi")`

Comment: Why do you need `elif`? You can just used `else` for your use case. In `elif` you'll need to use `and` to get the same behaviour not `or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `type` as it's a `builtin` name to get the type of a variable. And you can simplify your `if` conditions and your `while` loop to get the same structure as yoru other `while`

```
volunteer_type = input("Type of volunteer ('F/P/E/T'): ").lower()
while volunteer_type not in "fpet":
    print("Invalid type! Please enter again!")
    volunteer_type = input("Type of volunteer ('F/P/E/T'): ").lower()
```

---

Also you have a mistake, but you can't see it thank to how you did your code : `type != "f" or type != "p" or type != "e" or type != "t"` is **always** `True`, whatever `type` is, it'll **always** be different of one of the proposition, that `if` **is not** the boolean opposite of the first `if`, but as you put if as second `if` you didn't that problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume that using functions would make this code more simple:

```
def get_positive(message):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(message))
            if value <= 0:
                print("Not positive value")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Wrong value")
            continue
        return value

def get_type(message, possible_values):
    spv = set(list(possible_values.lower()))
    while True:
        value = input(message)
        if value.lower() in spv:
            return value
        print("Wrong value")


name = input("Name of volunteer? ")
age = get_positive("Age? ")
typ = get_type("Type of volunteer ('F/P/E/T'): ", "fpet")
hourCont = get_positive("Contribution hour? ")
newGroup.addVolunteer(volunteer(name, age, typ, hourCont))
print ("... Volunteer has been added successfully.")
```

P.S.
Do not use "type" variable as this is one of python own reserved words